# Spring boot Hikari connection pool issue after throwing exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

After some research and looking to similar errors posted in Stack Overflow I figured out this error is due to connection leak issue, usually happens when the connection is not closed and putting the connection obj **inside try block as in my code** resolves connection leak issue. I am wondering how this primary key violation caused the issue. Is there any extra code I should add to handle such exceptions?

I am getting the below error , this exception is continuously thrown

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:676) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:190) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:155) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:?]
```

My code which throws the error

```
   public void insertEvent(EventRequest event) throws Exception {
            try (Connection connection = this.fenxjdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
                    CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{call dbo.SPBIF_Insert(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}")) {
    
                call.setString(1, event.getXX());
                call.setString(2, event.getXXXX());
//some more call.setString code
                call.execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }
```

The code was working fine till I got three continues primary key violations error.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_T_EVENTS'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.T_EVENTS'. The duplicate key value is (8b4450fc-de74-5e91-b59e-fefe3b909667).
```

Congiuration:

```
 datasource:
           driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
           jdbc-url: jdbc:sqlserver://url
           username: db_username
           password: db_password
           hikari:
              max-lifetime: 86400000
              minimum-idle: 10 
              maximum-pool-size: 50 
              idle-timeout: 10800000 
              connection-timeout: 10000
```

Comment: Don't do `jdbctemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()`... That code is wrong, if you are doing thingsl ike that, get your hands of the keyboard, take 3 steps back and rethink your design decisions. If you want to call a stored procedure either use a `SimpleJdbcCall` (also from Spring) or at least use the `execute` method that takes a `ConnectionCallback` or the `CallableStatementCreator`/`CallableStatementCallback` to create and set the parameters. But don't mess around with the connection yourself, that will eventually lead to issues.